# Map 'f' to PageUp in vi

Tags: vim, button, dictionary, controls

I can map 'jj' to

`imap jj <Esc>`

and I can even map letters to tab navigation

```
map tj :tabprevious<CR>
map tk :tabnext<CR>
```

But I can't map g to page up (even though spacebar acts as page down)

```
map <Space> <PageDown>
map g <PageUp>
```

---

According to [this](http://hea-www.harvard.edu/~fine/Tech/vi.html) "When you try to map multiple key sequences, you won't be able to start them with lower or upper case letters ("Too dangerous to map that"), but the punctuation and control characters are fair game." Can anyone confirm this?

If so, how does one assign a function to an unmapped key like 'g'

Comment: g is a bit of a strange one. On it's own it does nothing, but it's not exactly 'unused'. In vim (the vi command links to vim in most systems) gg goes to top of file, 100gg goes to line 100, gj and gk are used to navigate long wrapped lines, so it's probably not the best choice either. I've updated my answer below with some new info. May I suggest the numbers 1 and 2 for PageUp/Down.

Comment: you already have ctrl-b and ctrl-f for pageup and page-down (or ctrl-u and ctrl-d for semipage up and semipage-down, ctrl-e and ctrl-y for line up and line down scroll)

Comment: @Benoit I gave up and started using ctrl-b/f/u/d but the ctrl button is really bad for the wrist b/c you have to constantly twist your hand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Edit - original answer suggested native Ctrl-f and Ctrl-b, but answer was updated as the goal here is to avoid using Ctrl and Shift)

A few points to add

Leaving the issue of choosing the right character to you, assuming we chose `X` for now.

I can think of two reasons why `map X <PageUp>` isn't working for you.

1. Your version of vi may not support PageUp/PageDown. If this is the issue then try instead to map to vi's page jumping  (B for back, accompanied by  for forward) eg. `map X <C-b>`.
2. Another other option is that it doesn't work 'as expected'. In vi PageUp/PageDown act on the 'viewport' not the cursor. So if you'r looking at the top of the file, but the cursor is not at the top  or  won't do anything. PageDown won't 'work' if your cursor is two lines from the bottom either.

   To address this you could combine the 'move viewport up' `<C-b>` and the 'move cursor to the top of viewport' `H` eg. `map X <C-b>H` (The opposite being `map X <C-f>L`). Or specifying the number of lines to jump yourself `map X 30k` (Op. `map X 30j`).

Then the issue of choosing the right character to overwrite. Vi has a lot of native commands, so many in fact that only a handful of characters don't do something natively.
So if your goal is to avoid RSI, then of course overwrite something. But make sure to overwrite something that isn't too useful for you personally.

Natively:
f searches for a given symbol on the line you are currnetly on (can be very useful, but not critical I guess)
g on it's own does nothing, but gg moves cursor to top of file. Choosing g may cause issus as vim (not the original vi) will interpret two quick keypresses as go to top of file instead of do two PageUp's.

Comment: I just started using vi SPECIFICALLY to address my [RSI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Repetitive_strain_injury) as a result of Ctrl + anything. I think the Ctrl button is the root of all evil (even after moving it up to where the shift button is). h , j , k and l are great, but I need options to move around more. Any suggestions?

Comment: That's a bit of a problem then. You can overwrite f if you want of course, but you might be better off overwriting one of the characters that doesn't have a native vi command. There aren't that many unused characters so CTRL, SHIFT or <LEADER> (commonly ,) are usually used, making most custom commands 2 keys at least.

Comment: The list of vi commands (including unused characters) is available here http://people.cis.ksu.edu/~bhoward/vi/vi60.html. But you can overwrite any of the used ones if you have a better use for a given character.  However many do use CTRL-k/j or Shift-k/j for page up down in vi. Shift k (or K) is unused and Shift j (J) is occupied but not that important.

Comment: I do not want to use shift or ctrl as they are in awkward places (actually all the buttons from tab to ctrl). I don't mind two buttons (space f for forward and space b for backward), but I want it so that if I hold it it continues scrolling, I don't want to hit the two buttons over and over again. I think the space bar acts as a good Ctrl button since it serves no other purpose

Comment: also enter is a good one to use as it carries out the same function as 'j'

Comment: btw I changed 'f' to 'g' to address my main problem

Comment: I think the problem has to do with some bizarre mapping to g. When I do `:map g` it returns `n  gx <Plug>NetrwBrowseX`

Answer (score 2):

This isn't answering your question, but I thought it may be helpful to the problem you are having with your RSI. It maps the spacebar to toggle between fast and slow move modes. Normally pressing j or k will scroll down one line. Pressing space will turn on fast move mode, where pressing j or k will scroll down/up 10 lines. Press space again to go back to normal. This will only work in vim, not just plain vi (most "vi" programs are just symlinks to vim anyway though).

It works in both normal and visual edit modes.

To use it, put this code somewhere in your `~/.vimrc` file:

```
map <Space> :call ToggleFastMoveMode()<CR>

vmap <Space> :call ToggleFastMoveMode()<CR>gv

let g:fastMoveMode = 0

function! ToggleFastMoveMode()
    let g:fastMoveMode = 1 - g:fastMoveMode
    if (g:fastMoveMode == 0)
        noremap j j
        vnoremap j j
        noremap k k
        vnoremap k k
    else
        noremap j 10j
        vnoremap j 10j
        noremap k 10k
        vnoremap k 10k
    endif
endfunction
```

Comment: **This is the answer.** `<rant>` I suffer self-inflicted Eclipse- and PyCharm-driven RSI as well, and continually lament Vim's default use of "<Ctrl>" key chords. As [puk](https://stackoverflow.com/users/654789/puk) suggests, hellacious wrist pain induced by incessant key chording in other IDEs is _why_ many of us adopted Vim in the first place. `</rant>` Thanks for this tiny bit of awesome!